# For an r-regular graph, does there exist a subgraph with r nodes such that each node in the subgraph has r-2 connections within the subgraph?

Tags: networkx, wolfram-mathematica, computer-science, graph-theory

Suppose, I have an r-regular graph. Does there exists a subgraph with r nodes such that each node in the subgraph has exactly r-2 connections with other nodes in the subgraph? For some graphs I have checked that this is true. For a 3-regular graph a line with three nodes, for 4-regular graph a cycle of 4 nodes; for a 5-regular graph and for 6-regular graph this is true. Is this in general true? Or does it require more conditions to be true?

Comment: Maybe this is a question better suited for https://math.stackexchange.com/?

Comment: Yes maybe. Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 0):

Consider a very basic 2-regular graph - namely a triangle (so r=2). Every 2-node subgraph has nodes with degree 1 (= r-1).

This appears to be a counter-example of what you are thinking.

Joel

Comment: What about for r>2? It is clear that for a 2-regular graph this will not be true. For r=3, 4 , 5 and 6 with 10 nodes I have checked that it is true. But as r increases checking it becomes difficult.

Comment: Take a r+1 node complete graph.  Any r-node induced subgraph is a regular graph of degree r-1.